# Laravel Upvote/Downvote system - AJAX Security

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How would I in Laravel create a secure upvote/downvote system like reddits or even the one on stack overflows that can't be loaded with fake ajax requests. (Sorry if I don't know the terminology).

I have 3 tables:

```
**User**
id

**Post**
id

**Vote**
id
user_id
post_id
vote (int)
```

My general idea is to when the up-vote or downvote button is clicked use JQuery to fire AJAX with POST data that has the post_id & the vote, either 1 for upvote, -1 for downvote). This will get picked by the the VotesController@vote route. The vote method would check if user is authenticated, check if there is a vote from the same user and same post, and if the vote exists: change it (downvote), else it would add it (upvote).

Heres my kinda-psudocode

```
function vote()
{
    //Checks if user is logged in
    if(Auth::check()){

        //checks if ajax request
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
                            //get my data
            $post = Input::post('post');
                            $vote = Input::post('vote');
            $user = Auth::user()->id;

            //checks if user voted
            $vote = querythatisnotyetcoded

            //if row exists 
            if($vote->count() > 0){
                //change row AKA DOWNVOTE
                Vote->vote = $vote // however you change values
            }
            else{
                //add new row AKA UPVOTE
                Vote::create([
                    'user_id' => $user,
                    'post_id' => $post,
                                'vote' => $vote
                ]);
            }
        }
        else{
            return "No Ajax Request";
        }
    }
    else{
        return "Not logged in";
    }
}
```

Please let me know if that logic is secure.

*edit: no clue why my code is half brown (Fixed it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
function vote()
{    
    if (Auth::check()) {

        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            $post = Input::post('post');
            $vote = Input::post('vote');
            $user = Auth::user()->id;

            // Grab the vote if it already exists.
            $entry = Vote::where('user_id', $user)->where('post_id', $post)->first();

            if ($entry->count())
            {
                $entry->vote = $vote;
                $entry->save();
            }
            else
            {
                $entry = new Vote;
                $entry->user_id = $user;
                $entry->post_id = $post;
                $entry->save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Not an AJAX request.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "User not logged in.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks OK-ish, though largely copied from OP's outline.. how does this address security, and rejection of spoofed AJAX requests, though?

Comment: Just a quick note, should be `Input::get()`.

Comment: Isn't it only input::get() when its getting GET data, I want my vote to be POST data

Answer (score 1):

How secure do you want it?  For "full" security, you need to run over HTTPS -- but you can get some moderate degree of security, without it.

To guard against users forging votes from other users, you need to check the User is logged in the current HTTP session. HTTP Session is implemented by a client-specific token or cookie, which is (generally) only visible to that user.

This simple approach would not, however, guard against orchestrated traffic sniffing or man-in-the-middle attacks, which could conceptually capture session tokens & falsify requests.

Defending against these can only be done with HTTPS or by having a "shared secret" (such as the user's password) known to the client & server but never sent between, aka using hashing. This uses the HMAC function to hash the password & a challenge, and only sends the resulting hash over the wire.

This works well for Login screens.

Unfortunately for voting, unless you can keep the password around in the browser, or some other shared secret with which to authenticate your requests, then it's not so easy. Doable for single-page AJAX apps, I'm not sure about others.

Comment: One upvote, one downvote. I intended to discuss the _security_ question specifically.. I assume the OP can already implement an AJAX request.